# How do I get in python the maximum filesystem path length in unix?

Tags: linux, python-2.7, path, filesystems, max-path

In the code I maintain I run across:

```
from ctypes.wintypes import MAX_PATH
```

I would like to change it to something like:

```
try:
    from ctypes.wintypes import MAX_PATH
except ValueError: # raises on linux
    MAX_PATH = 4096 # see comments
```

but I can't find any way to get the value of max filesystem path from python (`os, os.path, sys...`) - is there a standard way or do I need an external lib ?

Or there is no analogous as MAX_PATH in linux, at least not a standard among distributions ?

---

[**Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32812228/281545)

```
try:
    MAX_PATH = int(subprocess.check_output(['getconf', 'PATH_MAX', '/']))
except (ValueError, subprocess.CalledProcessError, OSError):
    deprint('calling getconf failed - error:', traceback=True)
    MAX_PATH = 4096
```

Comment: It's 4096 on Linux - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32795/what-is-the-maximum-allowed-filename-and-folder-size-with-ecryptfs

Comment: @jonrsharpe: no programmatic way to get at it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read this values from files:

```
* PATH_MAX (defined in limits.h)
* FILENAME_MAX (defined in stdio.h)
```

Or use subprocess.check_output() with [getconf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getconf.html) function:

```
$ getconf NAME_MAX /
$ getconf PATH_MAX /
```

as in the following example:

```
name_max = subprocess.check_output("getconf NAME_MAX /", shell=True)
path_max = subprocess.check_output("getconf PATH_MAX /", shell=True)
```

to get values and [fpath](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fpathconf.html) to set different values for files.

Comment: First things first - is `shell=True` used to avoid passing absolute paths ? And is this getconf call portable ? May I need root rights using it ?

Comment: 1. `shell=True` makes that the specified command will be executed through the shell
2. getconf call is portable in unix/linux systems, not in windows
3. root is not required

Comment: Alright  +1 for additional effort - 1. shell=True - I know what it does but what difference does it make here (I tested without - I get `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory` - why?)? In other words could you rewrite this with Popen ? 4. Apparently I should catch CalledProcessError __and__ OSError __and__ ....?

Comment: 1. Here you are:
`name_max = subprocess.check_output(["getconf", "NAME_MAX", "/"], shell=False)` 
=
`name_max = subprocess.Popen("getconf NAME_MAX /", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)`
=
`name_max = subprocess.Popen(["getconf", "NAME_MAX", "/"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)`

When you pass shell=True, Popen expects a single string argument, not a list. And if args is a sequence['1', , ], the first item specifies the command string, and any additional items will be treated as additional arguments to the shell itself.

Comment: 4. The minor difference is that check_output will raise a Python error if the subprocess returns a non-zero exit status. With Popen you can control that:
`name_max = subprocess.Popen("getconf NAME_MAX /", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
output, error = process.communicate()
retcode = process.poll()`

Answer (score 16):

The way to do it **correctly** is to use the `os.pathconf` or `os.fpathconf` with `PC_` prefixed names:

```
>>> os.pathconf('/', 'PC_PATH_MAX')
4096
>>> os.pathconf('/', 'PC_NAME_MAX')
255
```

Notice that the maximum length of a path **component** may vary from directory to another, as it is filesystem dependent, so you might have `os.pathconf('/', 'PC_NAME_MAX')` as 255 and `os.pathconf('/', 'PC_NAME_MAX')` as 12, say.

Comment: Thanks what is the difference with the accepted answer - why is `PC_` prefixed properties more correct?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D this calls a python function in a couple of nanoseconds, and the accepted answer executes a **unix shell** (bash) that executes a program that gets the value and returns that value as a string.

Comment: Thanks - I mean `PC_PATH_MAX` vs `PATH_MAX`. I guess PC stands for pathconfig? Seems strange that I query different variables

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D those are (unfortunately) the C library constant names, even though such is not necessary in Python. I do not know who is to blame.