# How to handle OSError: [Errno 36] File name too long

Tags: python, python-3.x, filenames, long-filenames

When handling the errors that occur when trying to create an existing file or trying to use a file that doesn't exist the `OSError`s that get thrown have a subclass (`FileExistsError`, `FileNotFoundError`). I couldn't find that subclass for the special case when the filename is too long.

The exact error message is:

```
OSError: [Errno 36] File name too long: 'filename'
```

I would like to catch the OSError that occurs when the filename is too long, but *only when* the filename is too long. I do *not* want to catch other `OSError`s that might occur. Is there a way to achieve this?

**Edit:** I know that I could check the filename against a length but the maximum filename length varies too much depending on the OS and the filesystem and I don't see a "clean" solution that way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python IOError exception when creating a long file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677234/python-ioerror-exception-when-creating-a-long-file)

Comment: @NuclearPeon: No. That's windows specific and the answers there do not answer this question. I specified that in the question.

Comment: You can try to get the max filename path, although there is no sure way to do this. Check this link out: https://code.activestate.com/lists/python-list/210662/ - check the length of the filename and notify the user if it's too long. Otherwise a try/except is your best bet as already listed.

Comment: I specifically asked how to catch the exact error. I don't want to check the length beforehand because of race conditions and because of inconsistencies of maximum filename lengths (as stated in the question).

Comment: The only other way to narrow down OSError I've seen is to check the 3rd parameter when the exception is thrown. See doc here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.OSError - relevant information: `For exceptions that involve a file system path (such as chdir() or unlink()), the exception instance will contain a third attribute, filename, which is the file name passed to the function.` You might have to come to the conclusion that Python doesn't have a sure way of doing what you want. File a bug.

Comment: Found another SO question that might help you out; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807560/how-do-i-get-in-python-the-maximum-filesystem-path-length-in-unix - Step 1: Get max length from this question. Step 2: In your OSError `except` block, check the path and filename length. Step 3: If it's above the determined lengths, you have your condition where filesize is too long. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simply check `errno` attribute of caught exception.

```
try:
    do_something()
except OSError as exc:
    if exc.errno == 36:
        handle_filename_too_long()
    else:
        raise  # re-raise previously caught exception
```

For readability you may consider using appropriate constant from [`errno` built-in module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/errno.html) instead of hardcoded constant.

Comment: But then I also catch the other `OSError`s that I _specifically_ don't want to catch!

Answer (score 8):

You can specify just how you want to catch a specific error such as [errno.ENAMETOOLONG](https://docs.python.org/2/library/errno.html#errno.ENAMETOOLONG):

**Specific to your question...**

```
try:
    # try stuff
except OSError as oserr:
    if oserr.errno != errno.ENAMETOOLONG:
        # ignore
    else:
        # caught...now what?
```

**Specific to your comments...**

```
try:
    # try stuff
except Exception as err:
    # get the name attribute from the exception class
    errname = type(err).__name__
    # get the errno attribute from the exception class
    errnum = err.errno
    if (errname == 'OSError') and (errnum == errno.ENAMETOOLONG):
        # handle specific to OSError [Errno 36]
    else if (errname == 'ExceptionNameHere' and ...:
        # handle specific to blah blah blah
    .
    .
    .
    else:
        raise # if you want to re-raise; otherwise code your ignore
```

This will grab all exceptions caused by errors in the `try`. Then it checks if the `__name__` matches any specific exception and any additional conditions you want to specify.

You should know there is no getting around the `except` if an error is encountered unless you specific a concrete exception.

Comment: But then I also catch the other `OSError`s that I _specifically_ don't want to catch!

Comment: @MaxMatti To "catch" and error you must "handle" it. The `if/else` sets the conditional that `if` the exceptions `errno` attribute is not equal to (`!=`), you write code to ignore it (however you choose to do so); `else` you've "caught" the right exception...now "handle" it.

Comment: I do not want to ignore it! I want to _not_ catch it. I stated that in my question: "I do _not_ want to catch other `OSError`s that might occur. Is there a way to achieve this?"

If there's a way to let the previous error propagate further if `errno` is not equal to `errno.ENAMETOOLONG` please add that to your answer. But currently I don't see how you plan to achieve that.

Comment: @MaxMatti Lets say you have two errors: E1 & E2. In your `try/except` you only want to catch is E2 which is the error you are currently focused with. You know the type (`OSError`) but that is not how the `except` statement works. It is a [built-in](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.OSError) and as such you have to refer to the `errno` module for its mapped error code. But what if the first error you got was E1? Because `OSError` is a built in, there is no `OSError.ENAMETOOLONG` to specify in the `except`. In both the answers posted, you can move along if not E2.

Comment: @MaxMatti Just because you check if the `OSError` is the one you specifically want to deal with doesn't harm the code. Whatever is being executed in the `try` statement is subject to `except` if there is an error encountered. There is no `except OSError as oserr if oserr.errno == errno.ENAMETOOLONG`.

Comment: I get the feeling that we're not speaking the same language. If I understand correctly you are catching _any_ `OSError`. I do not want to catch the other errors! Suppose I need to catch `FileExistsError` in the calling function: I can't catch `FileExistsError` in the calling function when I already catch `OSError` like you're suggesting.

Comment: @MaxMatti Check edit, is that more inline with what you were thinking?

Comment: Yes, you are catching all Errors, but you are re-raising the ones you aren't interested in handling.  In effect, this is the same as not catching the errors you do not want.